Excel Office Add-Ins manifest.xml doesn't like namespace prefixes
When building Excel Office Web Add-Ins, a manifest.xml file is required to describe the service.
Here is a simple one that opens a Taskpanel in Excel:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp
    xsi:type="TaskPaneApp"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
    xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
    >
    <Id>61b854ed-e679-4ae7-9c91-c04e9846f706</Id>
    <Version>0.0.0.1</Version>
    <ProviderName>MyProvider</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="MyDisplayName" />
    <Description DefaultValue="My Description." />
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.google.com" />
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Workbook" />
    </Hosts>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/excel/" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>

Here is the same manifest.xml modified to use a namespace prefix. It doesn't work.  Excel just ignores it and offers no error messages.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:OfficeApp
    xsi:type="x:TaskPaneApp"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
    xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
    >
    <x:Id>61b854ed-e679-4ae7-9c91-c04e9846f706</x:Id>
    <x:Version>0.0.0.1</x:Version>
    <x:ProviderName>MyProvider</x:ProviderName>
    <x:DefaultLocale>en-US</x:DefaultLocale>
    <x:DisplayName DefaultValue="MyDisplayName" />
    <x:Description DefaultValue="My Description." />
    <x:IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />
    <x:SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.google.com" />
    <x:Hosts>
        <x:Host Name="Workbook" />
    </x:Hosts>
    <x:DefaultSettings>
        <x:SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/excel/" />
    </x:DefaultSettings>
    <x:Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</x:Permissions>
</x:OfficeApp>

To an application, the two should be identical.  And, both formats validate cleanly against the Office manifest XML Schemas.

Am I correct? Excel should be able to handle namespace prefixes and I've made a mistake in translation.
Am I incorrect? Excel only works with undecorated XML elements and prefixes are not allowed.

(The eventual goal is to generate the manifest from XSLT, but I'm finding it difficult without namespace prefixes.)
Thanks.


Please say more about "it doesn't work". What do you expect to see and what do you actually see? 2.. What happens if validate the manifest Validate manifest?

